# How to figure out cause of SolverError in CVXPY using Gurobi

Tags: gurobi, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I'm running into issues on CVXPY. I used MOSEK and the exact same problem seems to solve to a solution. If I try to use GUROBI in the `solve()` method, it gives me a `SolverError` telling me to set `verbose=True`, which dos not seem to help either. The output for `solve()` is below. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```py
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.3.2                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:26 PM: Your problem has 16355 variables, 14412 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:26 PM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:26 PM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:26 PM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:26 PM: Compiling problem (target solver=GUROBI).
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:26 PM: Reduction chain: Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> GUROBI
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:26 PM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:31 PM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:31 PM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:49 PM: Applying reduction GUROBI
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:57 PM: Finished problem compilation (took 3.087e+01 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:21:57 PM: Invoking solver GUROBI  to obtain a solution.
Set parameter QCPDual to value 1
Gurobi Optimizer version 10.0.3 build v10.0.3rc0 (mac64[arm])

CPU model: Apple M1 Max
Thread count: 10 physical cores, 10 logical processors, using up to 10 threads

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SolverError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
example.ipynb Cell 20 line 1
----> 1 problem.solve(solver=cp.GUROBI, verbose=True)

File ~/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py:495, in Problem.solve(self, *args, **kwargs)
    493 else:
    494     solve_func = Problem._solve
--> 495 return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)

File ~/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py:1070, in Problem._solve(self, solver, warm_start, verbose, gp, qcp, requires_grad, enforce_dpp, ignore_dpp, canon_backend, **kwargs)
   1068 end = time.time()
   1069 self._solve_time = end - start
-> 1070 self.unpack_results(solution, solving_chain, inverse_data)
   1071 if verbose:
   1072     print(_FOOTER)

File ~/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py:1395, in Problem.unpack_results(self, solution, chain, inverse_data)
   1393     warnings.warn(INF_OR_UNB_MESSAGE)
   1394 if solution.status in s.ERROR:
-> 1395     raise error.SolverError(
   1396             "Solver '%s' failed. " % chain.solver.name() +
   1397             "Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more "
   1398             "information.")
   1400 self.unpack(solution)
   1401 self._solver_stats = SolverStats(self._solution.attr,
   1402                                  chain.solver.name())

SolverError: Solver 'GUROBI' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.
```

The below is the same problem's `solve()` output for MOSEK

```py
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.3.2                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:28:56 PM: Your problem has 16355 variables, 14412 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:28:56 PM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:28:56 PM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:28:56 PM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:28:56 PM: Compiling problem (target solver=MOSEK).
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:28:56 PM: Reduction chain: Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> MOSEK
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:28:56 PM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:03 PM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
/Users/user/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py:157: UserWarning: Objective contains too many subexpressions. Consider vectorizing your CVXPY code to speed up compilation.
  warnings.warn("Objective contains too many subexpressions. "
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:03 PM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:23 PM: Applying reduction MOSEK
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Finished problem compilation (took 3.448e+01 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Invoking solver MOSEK  to obtain a solution.


(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Problem
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Name                   :                 
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Objective sense        : maximize        
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Type                   : CONIC (conic optimization problem)
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Constraints            : 30767           
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Affine conic cons.     : 0               
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Disjunctive cons.      : 0               
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Cones                  : 14412           
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Scalar variables       : 57648           
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Matrix variables       : 0               
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM:   Integer variables      : 0               
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: 
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Optimizer started.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Presolve started.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Linear dependency checker started.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Linear dependency checker terminated.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Eliminator started.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Freed constraints in eliminator : 2
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Eliminator terminated.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Eliminator started.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Freed constraints in eliminator : 0
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Eliminator terminated.
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Eliminator - tries                  : 2                 time                   : 0.00            
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Lin. dep.  - tries                  : 1                 time                   : 0.00            
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Lin. dep.  - primal attempts        : 1                 successes              : 1               
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Lin. dep.  - dual attempts          : 0                 successes              : 0               
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Lin. dep.  - primal deps.           : 2                 dual deps.             : 0               
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Presolve terminated. Time: 0.04    
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Optimizer  - threads                : 10              
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Optimizer  - solved problem         : the primal      
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Optimizer  - Constraints            : 16350           
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Optimizer  - Cones                  : 14412           
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Optimizer  - Scalar variables       : 43233             conic                  : 43233           
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Optimizer  - Semi-definite variables: 0                 scalarized             : 0               
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Factor     - setup time             : 0.03            
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Factor     - dense det. time        : 0.00              GP order time          : 0.00            
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Factor     - nonzeros before factor : 4.81e+04          after factor           : 6.70e+04        
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: Factor     - dense dim.             : 0                 flops                  : 1.09e+06        
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: ITE PFEAS    DFEAS    GFEAS    PRSTATUS   POBJ              DOBJ              MU       TIME  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: 0   1.0e+00  5.1e+01  1.4e+04  0.00e+00   -1.441036880e+04  1.631204518e+00   1.0e+00  0.10  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: 1   2.9e-01  1.5e+01  7.5e+03  -9.59e-01  1.078798811e+03   1.479240959e+04   2.9e-01  0.13  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:30 PM: 2   1.2e-01  6.2e+00  4.4e+03  -8.57e-01  2.904365568e+04   4.144461932e+04   1.2e-01  0.14  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 3   9.0e-02  4.6e+00  3.5e+03  -6.59e-01  4.519531594e+04   5.681332578e+04   9.0e-02  0.15  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 4   2.9e-02  1.4e+00  1.3e+03  -5.31e-01  1.274823813e+05   1.349130385e+05   2.9e-02  0.16  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 5   1.5e-02  7.7e-01  5.6e+02  1.43e-01   1.703792241e+05   1.751587659e+05   1.5e-02  0.17  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 6   2.5e-03  1.3e-01  4.5e+01  4.97e-01   2.294870234e+05   2.304595812e+05   2.5e-03  0.18  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 7   5.4e-04  2.7e-02  4.5e+00  9.50e-01   2.398677055e+05   2.400782648e+05   5.4e-04  0.19  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 8   2.1e-04  1.0e-02  1.1e+00  1.00e+00   2.415629733e+05   2.416436379e+05   2.1e-04  0.20  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 9   1.1e-05  5.4e-04  1.3e-02  1.00e+00   2.425720405e+05   2.425761970e+05   1.1e-05  0.21  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 10  8.6e-08  4.3e-06  9.2e-06  1.00e+00   2.426263978e+05   2.426264310e+05   8.6e-08  0.22  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 11  9.3e-09  4.7e-07  3.3e-07  1.00e+00   2.426267917e+05   2.426267954e+05   9.3e-09  0.23  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 12  1.1e-09  5.8e-08  1.4e-08  1.00e+00   2.426268344e+05   2.426268348e+05   1.1e-09  0.23  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 13  1.9e-10  7.4e-09  6.2e-10  1.00e+00   2.426268397e+05   2.426268397e+05   1.4e-10  0.24  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: Optimizer terminated. Time: 0.26    
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: 
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: Interior-point solution summary
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM:   Problem status  : PRIMAL_AND_DUAL_FEASIBLE
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM:   Solution status : OPTIMAL
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM:   Primal.  obj: 2.4262683967e+05    nrm: 2e+02    Viol.  con: 2e-08    var: 0e+00    cones: 0e+00  
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM:   Dual.    obj: 2.4262683972e+05    nrm: 4e+02    Viol.  con: 0e+00    var: 2e-07    cones: 0e+00  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Summary                                    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: Problem status: optimal
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: Optimal value: 2.426e+05
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: Compilation took 3.448e+01 seconds
(CVXPY) Oct 01 09:29:31 PM: Solver (including time spent in interface) took 2.999e-01 seconds
```

Comment: I have no answer and I agree it looks mysterious but 1) the second compilation warns about a very large cvxpy model and 2) it takes 30 seconds to model and 0.24 sec to solve, which is outrageous. It would suggest that something is not as it should be - there is something very unusually complicated about your model and maybe you should change it anyway.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek - I haven't vectorized any of the constraints. I'm relatively new to convex optimization, so it could be this, but at the moment I'm just trying to test a theory. I will optimize when it is working better

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek - what steps can I take to find out?

Comment: Simplify the code as much as possible to still reproduce the error and contact either cvxpy or gurobi with fully reproducible code, if until then you cannot resolve it, would be my suggestion.

Comment: BTW it is actually much easier to write vectorized than not-vectorized code in cvxpy so just go for it.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek - The issue is that the dataset is very proprietary and thus would need the code to be changed in such a way that the dataset type can be backed out. Given these constraints, are there general directions I can go in to figure out what issues GUROBI could run into that other solvers may not? It works with MOSEK, SCS, and ECOS (that I have tested) and not with GUROBI

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek - How would I write vectorized code? Is it as simple as having variables in a vector/matrix instead of individual variables (ie. 1 1xn vector variable instead of n scalar variables)?

Comment: Yes that's the point.  Have a look at the CVXPY website, almost all examples there are like that. The difference between solvers may be caused by the fact that cvxpy has to produce a different internal problem to feed into each solver because solvers have different APIs/capabilities and so different reformulations are necessary. But I am out of my depth here to help, especially regarding gurobi.